# AS3 load images from sub-directory

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5.5

Is there a way to get all filenames within a subdirectory in flash using ActionScript?

From the research I've done, it seems like the answer is no, unless using AIR. This is not an option for me.

What alternatives are there? Can I do something like this using XML or something?

If so, where should I look to figure this out/what are some suggestions?

What I want to do is:
Load all filenames into an array, then use that array to load images into my swf.

Can this be done without AIR?

I'm using CS5.5.

Comment: Where are the files located? What's the problem with using air?

Comment: You can't do it with Flash alone. You could, for example, use an XML where all the files and folders are defined, but you would have to update that each time something in that directory changes. Alternatively, you could write a PHP script that will list you the contents of the directory and returns them to you AS3-side (At least I think that should be possible).

Comment: Flash alone without AIR won't be able to do it by itself (it's not able to read directories and directories contents).

Comment: What is the context of your application and the files you wish to retrieve?  If the files are on your server, then it's not too difficult to write a script that can send the list to your AS3 app.  If your swf is running in the browser and you want to list files from the users own computer, then thank goodness that is not allowed - there is no way around that nor should there be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a separate program (in AIR, or in something else) that scans a directory, generates an XML file, and stores it in a place where your SWF has access to it.

From there you can load the XML with Flash, parse it, and load your images.